# Check box checked on by default

Tags: checkboxes

Should check boxes be checked on or off by default? Also should they be enable or disable?

This feature does something cool.

[ ]Enable this feature or [x]Enable this feature

or

[x]Disable this feature or [ ]Disable this feature

Comment: I think this question is a bit vague, can you offer some context? Their is no  right and wrong answer without a question to explain how you are wanting to use it? If the feature is something that most people want then it should be enabled by default. If not then it should not.

Comment: I have a filter settings. Filter has a few checkbox options. disable/enable current filter, category, brand, vendor, and custom

Comment: You really have two questions here: "should checkboxes be checked by default?" and "should I label my checkboxes with 'positive' or 'negative' phrases?" And I think the answer to both is solidly in "it depends" territory, unfortunately. Like @stradled said, you need to find out what your users expect from this feature, and that'll be your default state, because that makes the system feel predictable and effortless.

Answer (score 1):

For start, it's better to have the text `Enable this feature` since it's a positive message. And based on how you predict the user would want, keep it enabled or disabled.

For instance, if you feel this is a cool feature everyone should have, turn it on by default

`[x] Enable this feature`

Else if you feel it's too intrusive to make that decision for the user and it's not cool enough to be subtly forced to all the users, turn it off by default

`[ ] Enable this feature`

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Check box should not be an action, (i.e. do something).

In your case, if I understand correctly, you can have something like,

```
[ ]Category1
[X]Category2
[ ]Category3

[X]Brand1
[X]Brand2
[X]Brand3
```

Where each checked items is an enabled filter.
The default state can and will be dependent on the context.
If having all items checked result in a large quantity of "hits" then, it might be more friendly to have all of them unchecked by default.

You can also have a button to check all check boxes.

```
(Check all categories)
[ ]Category1
[X]Category2
[ ]Category3

(Check all brands)
[X]Brand1
[X]Brand2
[X]Brand3
```